# rails test with jruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

Rails test is hanging on "Running"

I´ve installed the latest version of Rails and JRuby, create a new project with 'rails new ' following the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl.  Then I ran 'rails generate controller StaticPages home help' and tried to run 'rails test'.

Had expected the test to go through but it hangs on "Running" and nothing happens.

Don´t have any idea on how to debug this!

Comment: Forgot to say that I´m on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of reboots it started working.  Don´t really know why.  Will close it.